# Multiprocessing / Multithreading in Python..?

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, memory-management

I have a code which I wanted multiple times to be processed (multiprocessing), and the output of each of multiple process should be stored in one common memory and then processed accordingly.

Each individual process executes a piece of code (maintains a dictionary) and side by side each process should store the data in one common memory (either side-by-side or if not possible then store afterwards all the dictionary at the last.)

For .e.g

```
process1 ->  dict1,  
process2 -> dict2, 
process3 -> dict3

>main_dict = dict1 + dict2 + dict3
```

I am executing this piece of code in Python.

I can do multi-threading over here as well, but multi-threading is not so parallel actually as i have heard of... So I can go for multiprocessing. Please tell me the process as to maintain this kind of scenario in multiprocessing mode without wasting to much time or leaving the processor ideal..

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You're going to want to look at the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) module, although I don't think that you can do shared memory with dictionaries in Python -- I think you're going to need to serialize them and send them over a Queue.

> multi-threading is *not so parallel* actually as i have heard of... So I can go for multiprocessing. Please tell me the process as to maintain this kind of scenario in multiprocessing mode without wasting to much time or *leaving the processor* ideal..

If you don't want to leave the processor then you're not going to get any extra parallelism, unless you're IO-bound.

What that means is that if you're doing a huge amount of CPU work then staying on the same processor *and* doing multiprocessing *will only slow you down*. The only way to increase parallelism is to go to other processors. (Even if they're "virtual" hyperthreaded cpu's.)

If, on the other hand, you're slowed down by reading stuff in from memory or a network (which does not seem to be the case) the [threading](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html) module would be more reasonable. But it does not increase your CPU parallelism due to the [GIL](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)

In short: you're asking for contradictory things. Figure out what you actually need, and then choose one approach.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module.

In the documentation are many examples what you can do with it.
Eventually that could help you with your problem...

Comment: subprocess is better suited to launch external commands, OP seems to use python code.